# Cancel automatic focus on entry using xamarin telerik popup

Tags: xamarin, popup, telerik, focus

I'm using a Telerik RadPopup composed with an entry and checkbox's.
When I open the popup, the focus is directly is the entry. But I dont want a focus in any component.

It is possible using this type of popup ?

There is the code

```
<telerikPrimitives:RadPopup.Popup>
                    <telerikPrimitives:RadPopup Placement="Center" IsModal="False" OutsideBackgroundColor="#6F000000" IsOpen="{Binding WantSendEmail}">
                        <telerikPrimitives:RadBorder CornerRadius="8" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Key=LightBackgroundColor}">
                            <Frame HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Padding="0" Margin="0" WidthRequest="250">
                                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Key=MainButtonPrimaryColor}"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                        <Label Text="Envoi par Email" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontSize="{Binding FontSizeXSmall}"
                                               Padding="10"
                                               TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,0"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SaisieLibre, Converter={StaticResource cnvInverseBoolConverter}}" Color="{StaticResource Key=MainButtonPrimaryColor}"/>
                                        <ContentView Focused="ContentView_Focused" Content="{Binding EntrySearchTiers}" Padding="10,10,10,0"
                                                     IsEnabled="{Binding SaisieLibre, Converter={StaticResource cnvInverseBoolConverter}}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,0"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SaisieLibre}" Color="{StaticResource Key=MainButtonPrimaryColor}"/>
                                        <Label Text="Saisie Libre" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,10,10,0"
                                                 HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                                                 IsEnabled="{Binding CurrentUserHasContact}">
                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding CCEnable}" Color="{StaticResource Key=MainButtonPrimaryColor}"/>
                                        <Label Text="Recevoir une copie" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10,0,10,10">
                                        <Button Style="{StaticResource Key=BtnFlex}" Text="Envoyer" 
                                                WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="30" 
                                                Command="{Binding SendMailCommand}"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </telerikPrimitives:RadBorder>
                    </telerikPrimitives:RadPopup>
                </telerikPrimitives:RadPopup.Popup>
```

And the contentView :

```
        EntrySearchTiers = new SearchableEntry()
        {
            Style = (Xamarin.Forms.Style)Application.Current.Resources["MainEntryStyle"],
            FontSize = FontSizeMedium,
            Placeholder = "Liste des tiers"
        };

        EntrySearchTiers.Behaviors.Add(new Prism.Behaviors.EventToCommandBehavior
        {
            //EventName = "Completed", --> Jamais triggered
            EventName = "TextChanged",
            Command = TiersSelectedCommand
        });
        EntrySearchTiers.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, new Binding("CodeTiersSelected", BindingMode.TwoWay, null));

        Base.Views.Popups.ChoicesPopup popup = new Base.Views.Popups.ChoicesPopup(_serviceTiers, null, Guid.Empty, EntrySearchTiers, "code tiers :", this, serviceHistoChoice: _serviceHistoChoice, groupChoice: Enums.enumGroupChoice.Tiers);

        await popup.ActivateSearchEntryBehavior();
```

Comment: Why dont you use Rg.Plugin.Popup https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup

Comment: And also please post your code for more clarity

Comment: Because all my application using telerik component. Do we have the same behaviour with a Rg.Plugin.Popup ? If not, i can change for this.

Comment: Your issue is whenever the popup open, the entry is focused and keyboard appears. Is it? and also I didnt see any entry in your code

Comment: That's it. My entry is in my content view

Comment: Can you post the content view also?

Comment: is your MainEntryStyle   have focused set to true?

Comment: it isn't set, so I think its false by default